# What is the maximum number of characters in a currency symbol?

Tags: currency, accounting

In the program I am writing, I need to show a currency selector. I would like it to display currency symbols. For this, I need to know what is the longest, in characters, currency symbol (or rather what the maximum length can be, if there is any limitation).

E.g. USD, EUR, RUB all use single-character symbols: $, €, ₽. I initially assumed that it will always be one character. But I am obviously wrong, as e.g. Polish zloty symbol is zł.

Comment: Dollar (often represented by the dollar sign $) is the name of more than 20 currencies, including those of Australia, Canada, Hong Kong, Jamaica, Liberia, Namibia, New Zealand, Singapore, Taiwan, and the United States.

Comment: That's why the back-end of my program knows the official name of the currency, the ISO 4217 3-letter code and the symbol. For the user interface, however, as long as there are no clashes, a shorter and more familiar symbol is preferred. I might make it a setting to show 3-letter codes for the confusing situations, e.g. with US and Canadian dollars. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of currency symbols, some of which are used by more than one currency as @HotLicks suggests, you may want to consider the three-letter currency codes used in most currency exchanges. Here is a list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Active_codes.

Comment: For international banking system professionals, that would be undoubtedly a good choice. However in daily private finance, it might not be the best one. E.g. in Russia they use Cyrillic letters, and the sign for RUB is ₽. I am sure it would look strange to a Russian guy to see his milk pack costing `50 RUB`.

Answer (score 1):

[Suggestion of @herr-k](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/25551/20179) led me to this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_circulating_currencies. It lists all current currencies and their symbols.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard called ISO 4217. This standard contains currencies used in banking and business, and it used worldwide.

You can find a list [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.payments.developer.doc/refs/rpylerl2mst97.htm).

You can also find a CSV file containing every currency code [here](https://github.com/datasets/currency-codes/blob/master/data/codes-all.csv).